# Get modification time of a uniprot sequence using biopython?

Tags: biopython

Can I access the last modification date of protein sequence using biopython?
Thanks.
Petro.

Comment: Could you add some code that you are working with please? We need some more details

Answer (score 0):

```py
from Bio import ExPASy
from Bio import SwissProt

accession = "O23729"

handle = ExPASy.get_sprot_raw(accession)
record = SwissProt.read(handle)
record.sequence_update
```

Output:
`('01-JAN-1998', 1)`